# How do I subtract the previous row from the current row within a group in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I've got a table full of server requests like this:

```
User ID|Timestamp
010101|01-01-14 12:00:00 AM
010101|01-01-14 12:00:10 AM
010101|01-01-14 12:00:30 AM
020101|01-01-14 12:00:00 AM
020101|01-01-14 12:01:00 AM
020101|01-01-14 12:01:20 AM
```

I'd like to find the lag between requests. The resulting table would look something like this (Assume there was an intermediate step to convert timestamps to Unix format):

```
User ID|Seconds from last request
010101|0
010101|10  --12:00:10 - 12:00:00
010101|20  --12:00:30 - 12:00:10
020101|0
020101|60  --12:01:00 - 12:00:00 
020101|20  --12:01:20 - 12:01:00
```

Is there a way to do this in Hive?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to update to the latest version of Hive and [use the LAG function](http://www.qubole.com/big-data-analytics-using-window-functions/). See this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-896).